# Push the checked/selected item of checkbox at the top of the list in Angular9 and above

Tags: html, angular, typescript, checkbox, angular9

> I am trying to get the selected checkbox on the top the list Say If I
> selected fourth checkbox among five checkboxes(123**4**5) the result
> should be (**4**1235) please help for your reference I have added work
> done till now and add link also.

***TS file***

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })

    export class AppComponent {
      options = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'];
      selected = [];
    
      messages = [];
    
      // check if the item are selected
      checked(item) {
        if (this.selected.indexOf(item) != -1) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    
      // when checkbox change, add/remove the item from the array
      onChange(checked, item) {
        if (checked) {
          this.selected.push(item);
        } else {
          this.selected.splice(this.selected.indexOf(item), -1);
        }
        console.log(this.selected);
      }
    
      save() {
        this.messages.push(this.selected.sort());
      }
    }
```

*** HTML File ***

```
<h1>Angular Checkbox List</h1>

<h3>Options</h3>
{{options | json}}
<h3>Selected</h3>
{{selected | json}}
<br>
<h3>List</h3>
<div *ngFor="let item of options">
  <input type="checkbox"
  (change)="onChange($event.target.checked, item)"
  [checked]="checked(item)"
>
  {{item}}
</div>
<br>
{{selected.length}} items selected <br>
<button (click)="save()">Save</button>

<h3 *ngIf="messages.length != 0">Log</h3>
<div *ngFor="let item of messages">
  save: {{item}}
</div>
```

> ***list given***
>
> ```
> [] one (say I selected first this checkbox)
> [] two 
> [] three (second this checkbox)
> [] four
> [] five (next this checkbox)
> ```
>
> ***excepted resulted***
>
> ```
> []five
> []three
> []one
> []two
> []four
> ```

[working here stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-91nscs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
Add these two lines in `onChange` method

```
this.options.splice(this.options.indexOf(item), 1);
this.options.unshift(item);
```

**Note:** Stackblitz link is updated.

**Old:**
Just remove `.sort()` method from the line `this.messages.push(this.selected.sort());`. It will give the exactly selected items in the order you selected them.

I have modified it in your Stackblitz link- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wmimex

Comment: I need to re-order the list Say If I selected fourth checkbox among five checkboxes(12345) the result should be (41235) means 4 checkbox should got top among the List

Comment: Working sample is here but I need it in angular 9+ versions http://jsfiddle.net/L37fha9m/

Answer (score 0):

Add the index to the `*ngFor` in your HTML file.

```
    <div *ngFor="let i = index; let item of options">
      <input type="checkbox"
       (change)="onChange($event.target.checked, item, i)"
       [checked]="checked(item)">
      {{item}}
    </div>
```

So you can use it as parameter in your `onChange` function. That way you can remove from that index and push it to the top as this:

```
  // when checkbox change, add/remove the item from the array
  onChange(checked, item, index) {
    if (checked) {
      // Removes it from the index
      this.options.splice(index, 1);
      // Push it in the first position
      this.options.unshift(item);

      this.selected.push(item);
    } else {
      this.selected.splice(this.selected.indexOf(item), 1);
    }
    console.log(this.selected);
  }
```

[Here I modified your Stackbliz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-itp6uy?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

[Snapshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEoHk.png)

If you want the item to return to its original index when it is deselected:

```
  // when checkbox change, add/remove the item from the array
  onChange(checked, item, index) {
    if (checked) {
      // Removes it from the index
      this.options.splice(index, 1);
      // Push it in the first position
      this.options.unshift(item);
      this.selected.push(item);
    } else {
      // Removes it from the index
      this.options.splice(index, 1);
      // Place it in the original index
      this.options.splice(this.optionsCopy.indexOf(item), 0, item);
      this.selected.splice(this.selected.indexOf(item), 1);
    }
    console.log(this.selected);
  }
```

[Here the working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tkyjng?file=src/app/app.component.ts).